# How to check image quality in opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am kind of new to Image processing and OpenCV. In my project, I am doing OCR. But before that, I want to check quality of image is enough good or not. The library I am using for doing OCR says that image should have more than 300 DPI. As far as I know, DPI is related to printer/scanner.

So what can OpenCV give it to me which is directly proportional to DPI ?

Comment: if you the input dimensions (e.g. always A4) you can compute dpi

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, DPI is related to printer/scanner thus you will not find any information on that directly from the (pixels of) the images. However, such an information relative to the capture conditions may be present among metadata such as EXIF or XMP. In C++, you can use [libexif](http://libexif.sourceforge.net/) that is easy to include into a program that uses OpenCV. In Java, you can use [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor).

Comment: The metadata-extractor library is [also available for .NET](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet).